# Using a Javascript font select inside a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm currently using this script to select a font style, how would I include `name="font_style"` and `id="font_style"` to allow the selected font to be passed into a form and then submitted to the database.

Here is the script:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <!--
Copyright (c) 2015 by VISIONCAN (http://codepen.io/visioncan/pen/xLijC)

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
-->

  <title>CodePen - font-select dropdown</title>

  <style>
  body {
  background: #eee;
}

.font-dropdown {
  width: 220px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
.font-dropdown .label {
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  z-index: 2;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.font-dropdown .label:after {
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: "";
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-top: 7px solid #ccc;
  left: auto;
  right: 11px;
  bottom: 13px;
}
.font-dropdown .dropdown-list {
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 220px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-height: 66.66667px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.font-dropdown.active .dropdown-list {
  max-height: 200px;
  top: 37px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.font-dropdown.active .label:after {
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.font-dropdown li {
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.font-dropdown li:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2689d6;
}
.font-dropdown .sel {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: #2689d6;
}

  </style>

  <script>
    window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
    window.open = function(){ console.log('window.open is disabled.'); };
    window.print = function(){ console.log('window.print is disabled.'); };
    // Support hover state for mobile.
    if (false) {
      window.ontouchstart = function(){};
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <div ng-app="fdApp">
  <div class="font-dropdown" tabindex="1" fd-font-dropdown>
    <span class="label" ng-style="{{'fontslist[selectedIdx].style'}}">{{fontslist[selectedIdx].name}}</span>
  <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li ng-repeat="font in fontslist" ng-click="changeFont($index)" ng-class="{'sel': $index == selectedIdx}" ng-style="{{font.style}}">
          {{font.name}}
      </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>

  <script src='http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.min.js'></script>

  <script>
    if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
      window.parent.postMessage('resize', "*");
    }
  </script>

  <script src="//assets.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-6c99970ade81e43be51fa877be0f7600.js"></script>

  <script>
    (function () {
    var app;
    window.WebFontConfig = { google: { families: [] } };
    app = angular.module('fdApp', []);
    app.controller('FontDropdownCtrl', function ($scope) {
        var WEBFONTAPI;
        WEBFONTAPI = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
        this.FONTSLIST = [
            {
                name: 'Source Sans Pro',
                face: 'Source+Sans+Pro:900italic',
                style: {
                    fontFamily: 'Source Sans Pro',
                    fontWeight: 900,
                    fontStyle: 'italic'
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'Quattrocento Sans',
                face: 'Quattrocento+Sans',
                style: { fontFamily: 'Quattrocento Sans' }
            },
            {
                name: 'Ubuntu',
                face: 'Ubuntu:700',
                style: { fontFamily: 'Ubuntu' }
            },
            {
                name: 'Arizonia',
                face: 'Arizonia',
                style: { fontFamily: 'Arizonia' }
            },
            {
                name: 'Lora',
                face: 'Lora:700',
                style: {
                    fontFamily: 'Lora',
                    fontWeight: 700
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'Sansita One',
                face: 'Sansita+One',
                style: { fontFamily: 'Sansita One' }
            },
            {
                name: 'Armata',
                face: 'Armata',
                style: { fontFamily: 'Armata' }
            },
            {
                name: 'Black Ops One',
                face: 'Black+Ops+One',
                style: { fontFamily: 'Black Ops One' }
            },
            {
                name: 'Russo One',
                face: 'Russo+One',
                style: { fontFamily: 'Russo One' }
            }
        ];
        return this.loadFonts = function () {
            var font, s, wf, _i, _len, _ref;
            _ref = this.FONTSLIST;
            for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                font = _ref[_i];
                WebFontConfig.google.families.push(font.face);
            }
            wf = document.createElement('script');
            wf.src = ('https:' === document.location.protocol ? 'https:' : 'http:') + WEBFONTAPI;
            wf.type = 'text/javascript';
            wf.async = 'true';
            s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            return s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
        };
    });
    app.directive('fdFontDropdown', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: 'FontDropdownCtrl',
            link: function (scope, element, attr, Ctrl) {
                Ctrl.loadFonts();
                scope.fontslist = Ctrl.FONTSLIST;
                scope.selectedIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * scope.fontslist.length);
                scope.changeFont = function (idx) {
                    scope.selectedIdx = idx;
                    return console.log(idx);
                };
                return element.bind('click', function () {
                    return element.toggleClass('active');
                });
            }
        };
    });
}.call(this));
    //@ sourceURL=pen.js
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Could you please tell me if I'm doing something wrong or what I should add?
Many thanks

Comment: Looks pretty neat - I'd consider taking a look at some [javascript-database synergi stuff here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Comment: *Ran to the garden shack, got my spade and started digging into your code.* Please provide more information about your code. Which part isn't working?

Comment: It's not that any part isn't working, but I'm unsure how to include it into a form. Because at the moment it's just a select and show box in my words. And I have never before included javascript inside a form dropdown which can be submitted. Usually I have options etc and include the name-id & value at which is to be submitted. But I haven't got a clue what do to with javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `fd-font-dropdown`-div, you should include an `<input />`-element that will hold the selected font in the `value` attribute.

In the `changeFont`-function you're already setting the `selectedIdx` value, so this should do the trick:

```
<input type="hidden" name="font" value="{{selectedIdx}}" />
```

If you then place the entire `fd-font-dropdown`-dev in a form, the value of the `font`-input will be sent with it.

So, it would look something like this:

```
<form action="..." method="...">
    <div ng-app="fdApp">
        <div class="font-dropdown" tabindex="1" fd-font-dropdown>
            <input type="hidden" name="font" value="{{selectedIdx}}" />
            <span class="label" ng-style="{{'fontslist[selectedIdx].style'}}">{{fontslist[selectedIdx].name}}</span>
            <ul class="dropdown-list">
                <li ng-repeat="font in fontslist" ng-click="changeFont($index)" ng-class="{'sel': $index == selectedIdx}" ng-style="{{font.style}}">
                    {{font.name}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit the form" />
</form>
```